# Why my HTML code is not giving any result

Tags: html, vbscript

when I was running below code in IE9 it just displaying nothing. As per my understanding it should display "Hello World". As a Novice user I am very curious to know what would be the problem.
HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">

Function sayHello() 
   msgbox "Hello World"
End Function

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="sayHello()" value="Say Hello"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI this would only work in Internet Explorer

Comment: Hmm.. Age old script? `:P`

Comment: Hi Praveen, I did not understand ur question. But I am very curious to know why it is not giving any result when I click on button "Say Hello". Please help

Comment: @AlexK.: Even In IE also it is not giving any result after clicking on button "Say Hello"

Comment: Blocked content?  Your exact code worked for me on IE10, but I had to allow for the ActiveX.

Comment: Try to save it as SayHello.hta and try it !

Comment: @Hackoo: It worked well. Thanks for your suggestion.But any idea why it is not working on IE?